# How to add an icon before every ListView item text in an Android Application?

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I add an icon before every ListView item text in an Android application?

Here is the current list_item xml that is called to populate the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@color/darkblue"
/>
```

I attempted to add a ImageView before it, but it didn't show at all. Then I added a RelativeLayout around the entire thing and tried positioning them, but still it didn't show.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to do this is to use **drawableLeft**, **drawableRight**, **drawableTop**, **drawableBottom** tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@color/darkblue"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourPicture"

/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Relative Layout, just add the property android:layout_toRightOf to your TextView::

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myIcon"
        android:layout_width="25px"
        android:layout_height="25px"       
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="4px"
        />  
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@color/darkblue"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/myIcon"  
/>   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Isn't setting `xmlns:android` in the `TextView` a "copy/paste" mistake?